# Displaying busy status with thread in java

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm writing a Java app which writes to excel sheet bunch of data, and it takes a while to do so.

I'd like to create something like writing out dots to screen like on Linux when you're installing something.

Is that possible in java?printing dots, while other thread actually does the writing to excel, then after its finished the one displaying dots also quits?

I'd like to print dots to console.

Comment: Yes. If you also want to know how, please be more complete in your requirements. For instance, just where you want those dots displayed (console? web page? Swing GUI? ...?) - or better yet, ask us about which particular part of the problem you are having trouble with. (Is it the printing of dots? Asking another thread how far along it is? Starting a separate thread?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A variation to @John V. answer would be to use a ScheduledExecutorService:

```
// SETUP
Runnable notifier = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        System.out.print(".");
    }
};

ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);

// IN YOUR WORK THREAD
scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(notifier, 1, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
// DO YOUR WORK
schedule.shutdownNow();
```

Modify the notifier object to suit your individual needs.

Answer (score 0):

Its very possible.  Use a newSingleThreadExecutor to print the dots while the other thread does the parsing.  For example

```
ExecutorService e = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
Future f = e.submit(new Runnable(){
   public void run(){
       while(!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()){
          Thread.sleep(1000); //exclude try/catch for brevity
          System.out.print(".");
       }
   }
});
//do excel work
f.cancel(true);
e.shutdownNow();
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible, you will want to have your working thread set a variable to indicate that it is working and when it is finished. Then create a thread by either extending the `Thread` class or implementing the `Runnable` interface. This thread should just infinitely loop and inside this loop it should do whatever printing you want it to do, and then check the variable to see if the work is done. When the variable value changes, break the loop and end the thread.

One note. Watch your processing speed. Use `Thread.sleep()` inside your loop if your processor usage goes way high. This thread should not be labour intensive. `System.gc()` is another popular way to make threads wait.

Comment: System.gc() to make threads wait?? I fail to see how continually asking the VM to do a Garbage Collection is supposed to reduce CPU load?

Comment: It's not the most obvious, but I believe it has something to do with the fact that garbage collection is a low priority task, which means that the thread is more likely to be interrupted if necessary. I suppose, following that logic, if there are no other threads running then it would be considerably less effective, but that is pretty much never the case. Admittedly it probably just adds confusion to the answer, but I like providing options.

Comment: Even if `System.gc()` had that effect, I would't say that's a *popular way to make threads wait*

Comment: I believe the popular way you're looking for is Thread.yield() or Thread.sleep(0)

Comment: @everyone - deal with it. It works, its a solution. Note how I just threw it in at the end. My university professor showed me that solution on our first day of threads, so suck it.

And whoever downvoted a valid answer, you know what you can do.

Comment: Extraordinary claims require extraordinary evidence. Claiming that some unnamed professor showed you is not evidence, for you might have misunderstood him, or he might have erred (something that happened to my professors on occasion, too). At my university, students were encouraged to ask if we didn't understand something, not to "suck it", and professors even thanked us we pointed out the occasional mistake. I think you would benefit from that attitude, too - we are seeking truth after all, aren't we?

Comment: truth be told, i held the same attitude and frequently questioned many things (I recall pointing out a missing cealing function in an algorithm class when it was almost a joke cause there were already about 7 there). But I never questioned matters of opinion, such as what is "popular". And I see you didnt do that yourself, and i believe i answered your questions as best i could be bothered to anyway in my first response. my second response was directed solely at the "popularity" matter that i was unfortunately sucked in to.

Answer (score 0):

Not an elegant solution, but get's the job done. It prints 1, 2, 3, 1, 2... dots in a loop and terminates everything after 5 seconds.

```
public class Busy {

    public Busy() {
        Indicator i = new Indicator();
        ExecutorService ex = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
        ex.submit(i);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        i.finished = true;
        ex.shutdown();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Busy();
    }

    private class Indicator implements Runnable {

        private static final int DOTS_NO = 3;
        private volatile boolean finished = false;

        @Override
        public void run() {
            for (int i = 0; !finished; i = (i + 1) % (DOTS_NO + 1)) {
                for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
                    System.out.print('.');
                }
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(500);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
                    System.out.print("\b \b");
                }
            }
        }

    }

}
```